# Ошибка django 2.1. This engine did not provide a list of tried templates

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

учу django и возникает ошибка

> Using engine django:
> This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.

Код снизу
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import *
from .models import Bb, Rubric


def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics}
    return render(request, '/Users/tim/PycharmProjects/djangobook/bboard/index.html', context)
def by_rubric(request, rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.objects.filter(rubric=rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics, 'current_rubric': current_rubric}
    return render(request, '/Users/tim/PycharmProjects/djangobook/bboard/by_rubric.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Главная-доска объявлений</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Объявления</h1>
        <div>
            <a href ="/bboard/">Глвная</a>
            {% for rubric in rubrics %}
            <a href="/bboard/ {{ rubric.pk }}/"> {{ rubric.name}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% for bb in bbs %}
        <div>
            <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
            <p><a href="/bboard/ {{ bb.rubric.pk }}/" >{{ bb.rubric.name }}</a></p>
            <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

by_rubric.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content = "text/html; charset = utf-8">
        <title>{{ current_rubric.name}} - Доска объявлений</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Объявления</h1>
        <h2>Рубрика: {{current_rubric.name }}</h2>
        <div>
            <a href="/bboard/">Главная</a>
            {% for rubric in rubrics %}
            <a href = "/bboard/ {{ rubric.pk }}/">{{ rubric.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% for bb in bbs %}
        <div>
            <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ bb.content}}</p>
            <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а на линукс тоже будете полные пути прописывать? `'/Users/tim/PycharmProjects/djangobook/bboard/by_rubric.html',`. Почитайте документацию, как правильно работать с шаблонами, про структуру.

Comment: так ошибка не в этом

Comment: Ошибка именно в этом. Почитайте документацию всё-таки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается ошибка в том что html файлы у меня хранились вместе с файлами .py, а нужно было создать папку templates и туда поместить файлы html